# How put both sent messages and received messages in an archive folder in Mail.app?

Tags: apple-mail, rules

I have an archive folder that contains all messages I ever received on my mail account. The mail account is not a Gmail account. One thing I love about Gmail is that the threaded view not only shows messages I received but also messages I sent.

The only piece missing in this puzzle is the possibility for Mail.app to store a copy of all sent messages in my archive folder or to otherwise combine these two folders. Is this possible?

Comment: How about a smart folder that combines Sent + Archive?

Comment: @Daniel: Make this an answer and I will accept it. I have updates the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Smart Folders* to include all your Mail, e.g. with rules that match *any* of:

- Mail in your (inbox) Archive
- Mail in your Sent folder

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Mail.app has configurable 'rules' which allow this. I would, however warn that you may be substantially increasing the amount of space that Mail.App uses, since Mail.App stores messages differently than Gmail.

see http://rickcogley.blogspot.com/2008/01/tutorial-making-nice-with-mailapp-rules.html for several examples on how to configure Mail.App rules.